# Is Uranus the farthest object in Solar System that you can see with naked eyes?

Tags: planet, apparent-magnitude, naked-eye, uranus

The following text is from [this article:](https://earthsky.org/astronomy-essentials/uranus-at-opposition-closest-brightest-best/)

> The fact is, even at its brightest, **Uranus is still quite faint. It’s barely perceptible as a dim speck of light to the unaided eye, even under dark skies.** At a magnitude +5.6, Uranus shines no more brilliantly than the sky’s faintest visible stars. Given a dark sky free of light pollution, you might see Uranus with the eye alone. But you’ll need to have a good finder chart to know right where to look for this distant world in front of the rather faint constellation Aries.

There has been posts on other objects like [Callisto](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/36096/is-it-possible-to-see-callisto-with-the-naked-eye-when-its-at-its-greatest-elon), [Neptune](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/16399/have-there-been-successful-attempts-at-spotting-neptune-with-the-naked-eye) and even [Pluto](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/25503/did-i-see-pluto-with-my-naked-eye?rq=1) which has been confirmed as not possible. This makes Uranus the perfect candidate to be the farthest object in solar system that can be seen with naked eyes. Is this assumption true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, apart from maybe Neptune, which is within the "extreme naked eye limit", there are no other objects further than Uranus that have an apparent magnitude above +8.

See this list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparent_magnitude